# Files seemed to be locked in VS2013 using github source control

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a project with some classmates and we are using github to share files. Our code files are not sorted in the Solution Explorer at all and I am trying to fix that but all file files seem to be locked and will not let me change where they show up in the Solution Explorer. How do I unlock the files?

[image: What i am trying to do]

Comment: Please define "not sorted". I don't think this has anything todo with their commit status, but with you trying to do something that's  no supported.

Comment: Can you include a (set of) screenshots that illustrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to move those files into the folder i have at the top.

Comment: Because they are somehow locked i can't move them

Comment: Neither Git nor Visual Studio should be blocking this action. I ran a test locally and I do not run into this issue and can drag&drop just fine. Do you have any add-ons installed, try disabling tem? Updated to the latest update (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921)? Can you drag&drop on a project without source control integration?

Comment: I am on update 4 we have not used any plugins other than the github programs. I ran a test of my own any new file i create is unlock until i commit it to the repository. This problem is localized to this program.

Comment: Any error message? Is there a pre-commit hooi on thr repo? Does it happen on a repo that is not bound tot github (Create one using git init)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74124/discussion-between-jessehouwing-and-wolfcall).